# iPhone: is there a way to close an iAd bar?

Tags: iphone, button, iad

I'm trying to add iAd to my app right now.

I have it instantiated in my appDelegate, and would like to have a close button to allow the user to close Ad at any time.

How should I go about doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once a user has clicked on ad the ad will take over the screen. Full screen ads should already have a dismiss icon in the top left corner. They can also be programatically closed by calling the banner view's cancelBannerViewAction.

If you want the small ad to be removable by the user I believe you would have to implement the closing (X) yourself by adding a button into your view, linking it to an IBAction and calling the banner ads removeFromSuperview.